# Choose between two columns based on third column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have a Pandas dataframe containing three columns say A, B, C. I want to add column D to the dataframe whose values are taken from A and B based on values in C. For example, if C < 0.5, then D should contain value from B, otherwise value from A. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.where` for this:

```
import numpy as np

df['D'] = np.where(df['C'].lt(0.5),df['B'],df['A'])
```

This reads as, *for each row, if value in C is less than 0.5, return value from column B, otherwise, return value from column A.*

Note that you can replace [`lt(0.5)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) with [`le(0.5)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) to say *less than or equal to 0.5*.